# Difference between Telnet Will TN3270E and Telnet Wont TN3270E

Tags: telnet, ibm-midrange

While I'm connecting to AS400 via PCOMM emulator, in network traffic(using Wireshark) telnet protocol from source(client) to destination(server AS400) is showing as **Will TN3270E**, while I'm using TN5250j Emulator to connect AS400 in telnet protocol is showing as **Wont TN3270E**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Updated with screenshot

Comment: Although IBM i (formerly known as AS/400) primarily uses 5250, it actually supports 3270 as well. So, possibly, the IBM i telnet server is trying to work out if the client is 3270 or 5250. I think PCOMM actually supports both, whereas TN5250j only supports 5250, hence the different responses – https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaiw/rzaiwemultypes.htm

Answer (score 2):

This is telling you that one client supports TN3270E (TN3270 Enhanced) and the other one does not.  This is only relevant if you are doing something that requires the Enhanced standard (defined here from what I can tell: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2355#section-7.2.2).